# Jenkins pipeline scm environment variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to print the SCM last Git commiter name in pipeline job. 
The ${CHANGE_AUTHOR} returns null. 
I tried to do the following:

```
def scmVars = checkout scm
```

and print the results:

`println scmVars`

The commits and the details are fine. The problem is that the returned user is different. In the UI is as expected (Nir Koren):

```
Commit ********** by Nir Koren
```

But from the console logs GIT_COMMITTER_NAME and GIT_AUTHOR_NAME is a different user. In fact it's the technical user who created the SSH key to Github.

Any idea why it's different? Any clue how can I print the committers name before I am implementing ugly API call the the build URL?

Answer (score 1):

The GIT_COMMITTER_NAME is the user that the Jenkins server would commit as, and is unrelated to the change sets pulled down for the build.

Documentation states: 
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_NAME - The name entered if the "Custom user name/e-mail address" behaviour is enabled; falls back to the value entered in the Jenkins system config under "Global Config user.name Value" (if any)

You should be able to do this though:

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-